# Jenkins config file for Global Security - Security Realm - Jenkins’ own user database

Tags: ubuntu, security, jenkins, config-files

I need to find out where Jenkins stores its configuration data. Especially Global Security - Security Realm I tried to search `var/lib/jenkins` folder but without any success. Is there config file with this settings? I am not able to log in the Jenkins and I need to change it manually back.

[image]

Comment: Does [Securing Jenkins - Disabling Security](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/security/#disabling-security) help?

Comment: Thank you so much. It is back. Make an answer to accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### I am not able to log in the Jenkins

You can reset the Jenkins security:

> **Disabling Security**
>
> One may accidentally set up a security realm / authorization in such a
> way that you may no longer be able to reconfigure Jenkins.
>
> When this happens, you can fix this by the following steps:
>
> - Stop Jenkins (the easiest way to do this is to stop the servlet container.)
> - Go to `$JENKINS_HOME` in the file system and find `config.xml` file.
> - Open this file in the editor.
> - Look for the `<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>` element in this file.
> - Replace `true` with `false`
> - Remove the elements `authorizationStrategy` and `securityRealm`
> - Start Jenkins
> - When Jenkins comes back, it will be in an unsecured mode where everyone gets full access to the system.
>
> If this is still not working, trying renaming or deleting
> `config.xml`.

Source: [Securing Jenkins - Disabling Security](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/security/#disabling-security)